# Python code "freezes" after calling pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyautogui

I want to automate some clicks on Windows. I use pyautogui for that.

But when my code meets pyautogui.click(...), it execute it, and **after that** doesn't execute any other code except for pyautogui.

When I launch this code (I launch it through cmd with python myFile.py):

```
import pyautogui

print("Hello, World!")
pyautogui.click(500, 500)
print("Hello, World! x2")
```

It outputs:

Hello, World!

And then there is only blinking _

If I press any button (Enter for example) it outputs "Hello, World! x2" and returns control to me (so I can type any other command like cls, dir etc).

So instead of (Way #1):

1. Output "Hello, World!"
2. Click with coordinates
3. Output "Hello, World! x2"
4. Finish executing

It does (Way #2):

1. Output "Hello, World!"
2. Click with coordinates
3. Pauses until I press a button.

Why is that?
What should I do to run code Way #1?

By the way, if I write:

```
import pyautogui

print("Hello, World!")
pyautogui.click(500, 500)
pyautogui.click(600, 600)
print("Hello, World! x2")
```

It **does** click two times and then "freezes" the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure that the click is outside the command prompt window. You may use `pyautogui.mouseDown` paired with `pyautogui.dragRel` for this.

So, what is really going on there? If you click in the command prompt window, it starts "selection mode", and the code runs in the background until a key is pressed. [More on what really goes on](https://superuser.com/questions/459609/what-does-it-do-exactly-if-i-click-in-the-window-of-cmd).

I assume you wish to automate something. I suggest: make a .bat to go with your .py file; then, use pyinstaller from the command prompt to make a .exe file, and schedule it to start as often as you need. You could follow [this tutorial](https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably already done this, but I would check everything for updates (pyautogui, python, maybe your devise), because it works for fine me.
[python terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE106.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).